# High Speed design rules for 10GHz

Tags: layout

When any layout is called High Speed Layout? What are the pins we should look for considering any board layout as a high speed design?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. "High-Speed" is a relative term. It depends on what your used to working with as your version of "High-Speed". 10GHZ is darn fast. FR-4 is not good enough in some cases. Teflon boards with gold-flash over silver plated copper. If such speeds are confined to an input (gold plated 25 ohm mini) and pre-scaler IC then things are much simpler

Comment: Only considering frequencies can be counted as a High Speed Design??What other things do we refer in schematics?

Comment: Take a class on EM theory

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

In Microwave engineering, we often say we are dealing with "RF" when you are working with devices and interconnects that are longer than a few tenths of a wavelength. At this point, classic nodal and lumped element analysis no longer works, and care must be taken to include distributed effects, work with transmission lines and think in terms of reflections and S-parameters.

In other words, when making a large system like a industrial machine or communication network, it could be that a MHz is already "high speed". But when working on-chip, even at 10 GHz, we might be able to work with lumped inductors and capacitors, as they are still very small with respect to the wavelength.

Comment: HI Joren, As you mentioned related to RF designs, we need to take care for PI network 50 ohm trace, it should be straight and short...what else we should take care?

Answer (score -1):

Good morning and welcome! the definition of high speed from an RF perspective may be based on the properties of the medium or the geometry looking at the pcb, or at the rise/fall times and propagation times (and jitter or phase noise) looking at components.

As said, FR4 above 1 GHz begins a remarkably non-ideal behavior, but there are many FR4s around, all Flame Retardant, with different epoxy and glass % and properties. Geometry means length of traces, distribution to ICs in parallel (bus or tree arrangement), density of the board and crosstalk between traces, for which you shall go for microstrips or striplines, and in all cases it will be hard to distribute signals in parallel on long traces with significant local capacitive loading due to ICs.
Just for digital when going fast you shall trim equal the length of traces bringing parallel signals and avoid uneven loading of nearby traces (loading by inductive, or maybe but less, capacitive coupling).

At 10 GHz the size of vias too is embarrassing and they represent a significant reactive loading, not to say a stub.

It is quite difficult to be exhaustive on this topic. A good reference although a bit old is Johnson, High speed digital design. Then there are good IEEE papers and a few app notes by HP. I myself wrote a book on design and testing of such things 3 years ago.

Comment: Hi Andrea, For which components we should refer rise and fall timings?? Before starting layout what should be referred in schematic to such parameters of High Speed?

Comment: in terms of Interfaces which are used is fine....What other we should look for??

Comment: Hi Hardik. Components depend on your application. Take the example of a logic buffer (such as 244) driving a bus: you have a clock, but signal quality depends on the reproduction of edges of the ideal square wave, and the bandwidth of the resulting spectrum to transmit over the traces is determined for the higher frequency content by rise and fall times. Fast TTL or ABT has few ns, but EL is 10 times faster: as approx rule 1/(pi*risetime) and take min fifth harmonic, not to say tenth; this is the max freq to transfer correctly. You shall worry of atten, phase and reflection back from far end

Comment: For such high frequencies, Simply routing short and impedance  matching trace can work as well as enough return path for such signal and reference ground plane....something more you can add???

Comment: Could you please be more precise on your design choices, I don't understand